# Agregar opción de compartir en redes un archivo .Mp3 ya por default en la app en android

Tags: java, android

Estoy programando en Android Studio y no encontré tutorial ni foro que diga cuál es el código específico para compartir archivos .Mp3.

Sí encontré cómo compartir texto y fotos, pero no archivos de audio. Por favor, si pudieran responder seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Mediante el MIME TYPE de un archivo .mp3 que es `audio/mpeg` puedes usar `Intent.createChooser()` para compartir este tipo de archivo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Enviar .MP3"));
```

obviamente la ruta del .mp3 debe estar en el bundle.

---

Agrego un ejemplo completo creado por [@2Dee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21428893/250260)

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_audio_file_title)), REQ_CODE_PICK_SOUNDFILE);
```

Se obtiene la Uri en `onActivityResult()` :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_PICK_SOUNDFILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)){
            Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
            // Now you can use that Uri to get the file path, or upload it, ...
            }
        }
}
```