# Imagenes, Botones, Sonidos y Share en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, botón, whatsapp

Hola como andan? les cuento soy estudiante de Java (recién empiezo) y quice probar hacer una aplicación en Android siguiendo algunos tutoriales de YouTube, la logre realizar y ahora la quiero mejorar, me encuentro con algunos problemas que paso a detallar:

1) Quice mejorar los botones, para ello puse un ImageButton a la cual le puse una imagen que esta en mi res>dawable y es jpg de fondo tiene el boton gris el cual cuando voy a "Background" y le cargo ic_launcher_foregraund me aparece en la parte superior derecha un error de compilación el cual dice "Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_launcher_foreground", en la carpeta drawable tengo un xml que se llama "ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24)" cuando abro este archivo no aparece ningun error en el codigo (osea nada en rojo), quizas me falta escribir algo, ya le he dado a Clean Project, Rebuild Project, he ido a File>Invalidate Caches/Restart y sigue el problema, con otros botones que no usan imagen no me pasa.

2) La aplicacion cuando la quiero probar con el celular se abre y se cierra sola con un cartel que dice "la aplicación ha dejado de funcionar" o algo asi, quiero aclarar que Android Studio no me marca errores en ningun archivo, el error que comente en la pregunta anterior sobre "Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" se va cuando borro lo que dice en Background en el boton por ende no figura ningun error ni en el MainActivity ni en la parte de Text, lo unico que sale es abajo cuando despliego el boton de run que aparece esto:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas, PID: 14619
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas/com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

donde dice caused by yo lo tengo declarado en el MainActivity como:

```
Button peroperoperopero;
peroperoperopero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.peroperoperopero);
peroperoperopero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.peroperopero);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

por ahí el error esta ahí ya que en una parte en el error del build dice esto:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
```

pero no me aparece en rojo ni me marca error el MainActivity.

3) No se que codigo escribir para que cuando un boton esta reproduciendo un sonido y se preciona otro boton, este primer boton que estaba reproduciendo un sonido pare y se empiece a reproducir el otro boton, actualmente si preciono dos botones se reproducen los dos y como son sonidos largos se suman y no se entiende nada, también me gustaría saber que codigo escribir para precionar un boton que reproduzca el sonido y que cuando yo vuelvo a tocar ese boton mientras lo esta reproduciendo este pare actualmente tengo este codigo:

```
peroperoperopero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.peroperopero);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

4) Por ultimo me gustaría saber que codigo escribir para poner un boton de share (compartir) en WhatsApp y redes sociales los sonidos de esta botonera.

Perdon por lo extenso de la pregunta, soy bastante nuevo en esto y hay muchas cosas que se me escapan, avisenme si no se entiende algo o si tengo que postear alguna codigo que este haciendo falta para que se entienda alguna de las preguntas que hice.

Answer (score 0):

1) "Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_launcher_foreground", en la carpeta drawable tengo un xml que se llama "ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24)". En este caso el archivo `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` debe encontrarse en el directorio `/drawable` y no únicamente en `/drawable-v24`, revisa esta situación.

---

2) "Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_launcher_foreground", esto se resuelve con lo que indico en el punto 1.

Ademas : Me parece que de acuerdo a tu mensaje de error,

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.Button
>       at com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)

el botón con id `peroperoperopero` es un `ImageButton` y no un `Button`, realiza el casting adecuado:

```
//Button peroperoperopero;
//peroperoperopero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.peroperoperopero);
ImageButton peroperoperopero;
peroperoperopero = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.peroperoperopero);
```

---

3)Debes revisar si se esta reproduciendo un sonido, si es así debes detener y liberar el recurso para iniciar una nueva reproducción, si no se esta reproduciendo simplemente inicia el `MediaPlayer` como lo estas realizando.

```
  if(mp.isPlaying()){ //Play a new sound
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,x);
  }else{ //Play sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.peroperopero);
        mp.start();
   }
```

---

4) revisa:

[Agregar opción de compartir en redes un archivo .Mp3 ya por default en la app en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43164/agregar-opci%C3%B3n-de-compartir-en-redes-un-archivo-mp3-ya-por-default-en-la-app-en)

Comment: Hola Jorgesys muchas gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo que me dijiste con respecto al ImageButton pero con respecto a lo que me respondes en la 3 ahora me sale esto:

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)"

Comment: copie el codigo como me lo escribiste y sound me aparecia en rojo, asi que Android me sugirió crear " private MediaPlayer sound;" lo hice y dejo de estar en rojo, ademas en la x que esta en el mismo lugar del sound (sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,X);) puse lo mismo que abajo osea "(this,R.raw.peroperopero)" no aparece nada en rojo, asi que no se cual sería el problema.

Comment: La pregunta 1 y 2 quedo respondida! lo pude resolver yendo a la opción de Background y en lugar de abrir el archivo directamente escribir @drawable/ic_launcher_background por que yo ya tenia el .xml en el deawable pero no me lo tomaba.
Con respecto a  la 4 voy al link que me decís pero no me queda del todo claro por que debería crear un boton primero para compartir no? y entonces no entiendo como relacionar el codigo que me planteas en la respuesta a esa pregunta con el boton que debería crear.

Comment: Cree un boton de share lo inicialice y le pegue este codigo 
   sharebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent shareAudioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareAudioIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
                shareAudioIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse("file://"+ peroperoperopero));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareAudioIntent, "Share MP3 with:"));
            }
        });

Comment: peroperoperopero es un boton que esta inicializado y que me anda en la app y me reproduce el sonido que quiero compartir. Cuando pruebo la aplicación y toco el boton de share me aparecen opciones para compartir entre ellas WhatsApp pero cuando lo comparto a un grupo sale un cartel que dice "fallo al compartir por favor intentalo de nuevo".

Comment: falla aunque en el lugar donde dice peroperoperopero ponga R.raw.peroperopero (que es el archivo mp3).

Comment: Te sugiero revises si el ImageButton también tiene el id peroperoperopero @LucasFajersztejn . Si tienes un mp3 llamado peroperopero dentro de /raw es correcto cargarlo mediante el id raw.peroperopero

Comment: Yo creo que el problema esta aca "Uri.parse("file://"+ peroperoperopero)); " en donde dice "file//" que lo deje asi, que tendría que poner al lado el boton o el archivo mp3?